# Chat application for messaging and occasional file sharing

Tags: bootstrap-4, chat, instant-messaging

I have to develop a messaging app where people who work on the same project can message each other and occasionally share files. If I can add video to it, it would be great. The tool/platform needs to be opensource as we dont have any budget to pay for servers.

I have looked at **Matrix, Jitsi, Wire** and some other ones and I am now very confused. Messaging is only one part of our application (which **runs on Android and iOS**). We are using **Bootstrap** for our work so I can use javascript libraries.

In brief the app

*Allows people to be in multiple projects (say 5 projects). So John (our user) has 5 projects and he can work on each one with 2 to 3 other people where they share their questions and screen shots. It would be great if they can use video to chat, but not necessary at this stage.*

Having looked at the above platforms, I am not sure

1. do I really have to use them?
2. is there anything else I can do to solve the problem?

I like to know if anybody has been down this route and any suggestions/tips to help us pull this together.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try using mean stack to do this project. you can do a bit research on that and for chatting you can use socket io

Comment: Thank you. I have to stay with our existing tech stack and due to time frame, need to pick a solution which sort of works out of box.

Comment: what is the stack?

Comment: We use node.js, bootstrap 4 and mysql database.